# How to add first Cucumber test to a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, rspec-rails

Confession: I have never written a single test for Rails.

I have installed the gems cucumber, rspec, capybara, factory girl. Running Rails 3.1.

I am not sure, um, where to create a new test file or what to name it.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

Micheal Hartl has a good tutorial on Rails that is mostly test driven:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
You probably know most of this but it will point you in the right direction.

Here's a Rails Cast on Cucumber:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber

Here's an RSpec Rails Cast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec

Here are a bunch of Cucumber examples:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/examples/i18n

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

after installing the rspec and cucumber 
you must run following commands

**rails generate rspec:install** for rspec

first command
will configure rails generate command and it will create the spec directory which will contain tests for your models, controllers, views in respective directory you can write the
rspec test

eg. If you are having user model then specs for user will go in

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

that's it

to run these tests use

**rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb**

which will output the whether the tests are passed or not

cucumber describes the behavior of application

and rspec describes behavior of object

***rails generate cucumber:install*** for cucumber

which will create features directory in your application root

inside that you can write cucumber test with .feature extension

eg. If your application have feature like creating user, this feature will go in

features/creating_user.feature file

and the step definition for this feature will go in

features/step_definitions/create_user_steps.rb

well its just short guide line you can refer the following links

for cucumber
**http://loudcoding.com/posts/quick-tutorial-starting-with-cucumber-and-capybara-bdd-on-rails-project/**

Answer (score 1):

Think what is the most common way for people to use your app. Write a test for the 'happy path', ignoring any edge cases.

Next, write tests for the parts most likely break.